# converting a full matrix to a full matrix is slow?

Tags: matlab, matrix, sparse-matrix

I noticed that converting an already full matrix to a full matrix is slow:

```
>> tic; for k = 1:100; x = uint16(ones(10000,100)); end; toc
Elapsed time is 0.035748 seconds.
>> tic; for k = 1:100; x = uint16(uint16(ones(10000,100))); end; toc
Elapsed time is 0.034180 seconds.
>> tic; for k = 1:100; x = full(uint16(ones(10000,100))); end; toc
Elapsed time is 0.460977 seconds. %%%%% SLOW!
```

I tested without the `uint16` as well:

```
>> tic; for k = 1:100; x = ones(10000,100); end; toc
Elapsed time is 0.060028 seconds.
>> tic; for k = 1:100; x = full(ones(10000,100)); end; toc
Elapsed time is 0.229058 seconds. %%%%% SLOW!
```

Same effect.

Why is this? `full` is supposed to only convert sparse matrix to full matrices. If it is already full, shouldn't it do nothing?

EDIT: `issparse` is superfast! I guess being a MEX, it's mostly memory cost?

MATLAB Version 7.13.0.564 (R2011b) on Mac OS X

Comment: What is the context for this? If it is slow, then don't do it. Use `issparse` to test if you actually need to convert.

Comment: Maybe it's not converting, just checking if it has to, and that's the slow part ?

Comment: @DominiqueJacquel I already changed my code to do `issparse` before `full`. It's a bit cumbersome, but I'll live. This is mostly out of curiosity.

Answer (score 1):

`full` works just fine.

The slow part is actually the `ones(10000, 100)`... here's the proof:

```
>> tic, for k = 1:100, x = ones(10000,100); end, toc
Elapsed time is 0.043143 seconds.

>> A = ones(10000,100);
>> tic, for k = 1:100, x = full(A); end, toc
Elapsed time is 0.000081 seconds.
```

`full` is invoked with a non-sparse matrix and runs fast, hence it is not the reason for the slowdown.

Comment: But the question shows that `tic; for k = 1:100; x = uint16(ones(10000,100)); end; toc` is fast. How is that possible?

Comment: This part is probably JIT optimization like you mentioned, but I'm not sure. Go figure...

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer:** This is my best guess about what is happening, but I don't know for sure what goes on under Matlab's hood. **Update:** In a comment, [EitanT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1336150/eitant) pointed out that my guess is most likely wrong.

I think that Matlab's [JIT engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) is doing optimizations in some of these cases, but not all.

When you have a loop where a variable is created but never used, the JIT engine doesn't bother creating that variable over and over. It just does it once. Anything like this will be fast:

```
% this calls 'ones' once
for i = 1:100, x = ones(10000,100); end
```

But if you create a variable and then use it, say by passing it to a function, that variable is created every time. This takes more time, obviously.

```
% this calls 'ones' every iteration to pass to `full`
for i = 1:100, x = full(ones(10000,100)); end
```

Comment: I disagree with your argumentation. `for i = 1:100, x = ones(10000,100); end` is definitely much slower than `A = ones(10000, 100); for i = 1:100, x = A; end`. Also, in my answer I prove that `x = full(A)` is rather fast, which contradicts your statement that it should take more time.

Comment: @EitanT I agree with your first point and updated my answer. To your second point, `A` is created just once. I argued that creating the matrix to pass to `full` was slow part.

Comment: So according to you, using `x = full(A)` in a loop should be significantly slower than just `x = A`, but this is not the case...

Comment: I don't have Matlab here. Could anyone time a loop with `x = ones(10000,100,'uint16')`. Maybe Matlab optimizes `x = uint16(ones(10000,100))` by directly creating a uint16 array of ones.

Comment: @EitanT No. I said that `ones` is slow. `full(ones(...))` in a loop calls `ones` many times. Your test with `full(A)` in the loop only calls `ones` a single time.

Comment: @EitanT We're really just guessing with all of this stuff. We don't exactly what it will optimize or how it does it.

Comment: @DedekMraz `uint16(ones(...))` is probably slower than `ones(..., 'uint16')`, like shown [here](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/preallocation-performance/).

Comment: @shoelzer If you say that JIT optimizes a loop with `x = ones(...)` to call `ones` only once, and `full(A)` also calls `ones` only once by definition, then my answer shows that the reason for the slowdown is the invocation of `ones` (even if only one time). In any case, I clearly show that `full` by itself is fast, even when the input is non-sparse. But yeah, it's just me speculating.

Comment: @EitanT I agree that `full` is fast and `ones` is slow. The only question is what the JIT is doing to the loops. I still think there's something about calling `func(ones(...))` in a loop that trips up the JIT, but none of the tests we're doing conclusively prove or disprove that.

Comment: @shoelzer The question implies that the OP is only interesed in determining whether `full` is fast or slow, but I can be wrong. The JIT part remains a mystery...

Comment: @EitanT I interpreted the question to be "Why is `full` slow in my test code?" I attempted to explain that. But +1 to your straightforward answer that showed he was measuring the wrong thing.